# Is there any way to get the DNS address of an instance of an aws ubuntu server if I do not have the login to the aws account, but the SSH key for it

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I got a task to deploy a static website on an AWS Ubuntu Server, I was given the username and the SSH key for it. Using PuTTy I got access to the server, setup django, postgres nginx and gunicorn. However now I need to check the progress and whichever tutorial I looked up, I found them checking their deployment progress with a dns address, but since I have connected to the server remotely, I do not have that. So please help me check my deployment status. I am attaching some screenshots of the PuTTy terminal below

[Image of the final Gunicorn command to finish the deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hctqr.png)

Comment: If you were tasked to deploy a static website, what do you need Django and Gunicorn for..? Anyway, a server can have _any number_ of DNS names pointing to it, so what name are you looking for?

Comment: @AKX they asked me to configure these things despite it being a static site. I just mean to ask how can I get a url where I can see if my site is being deployed properly

Comment: Well, since you already have an SSH connection, you can use SSH port forwarding to see how the site would look like.